# add class if child category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've got this code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms("category");
$count = count($terms);
$url= get_bloginfo("url");
 if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<ul class='spis_kate'>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$nazwa = $term->name;
$wyswietl= strtolower($nazwa);
$przed = array ('ą', 'ę', 'ó', 'ś', 'ć', 'ń', 'ź', 'ż', 'ę', 'ł', ' ');
$po = array ('a', 'e', 'o', 's', 'c', 'n', 'z', 'z', 'e','l', '-');
$wynik= str_replace($przed, $po, $wyswietl);
   echo "<li><a href=".$url."/produkt/?category_name=" . $wynik. ">" . $term->name . "</a></li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
 }
?>
```

How to add a class (for example child) to the li if the category is child.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the built-in [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) instead. It will give you a nested list.

```
<?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
```

I can also see that you are generating your own slug. The already generated slug can be found at `$term->slug`.

However, if you for any reason need to know whether a particular term has a parent, you could check the value of `$term->parent`. If it is not set, it means that the term is at the top level.

```
<li class="cat<?php if ( $term->parent ) echo " child"; ?>">
```

Comment: It is not clear to me from your question why your links must be custom, but I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$li_class=($wynik==="child")?"child":"";
echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><a href=' ...
```